# Add image programmatically to nested ToolStripMenuItem via ImageIndex

Tags: c#, image, winforms, menu, menuitem

I have a menu structure as seen in picture below:

[image]

I want to add images to all submenu-items under the controllerToolStripMenuItem, ie openToolStripMenuItem, openInNewWindowToolStripMenuItem... *ImageList* contains my images to use and *menuStrip1* gets a reference to the list of images :

```
menuStrip1.ImageList = ImageList;
```

Test code:

```
private void LoadSubMenuIcons()
{
    menuStrip1.ImageList = ImageList;

    //Just for test:
    controllerToolStripMenuItem.ImageIndex = 2;
    ToolStrip firstLevelParent = controllerToolStripMenuItem.GetCurrentParent();
    //firstLevelParent.ImageList is of type MenuStrip 
    //firstLevelParent.ImageList equals ImageList set above

    foreach (ToolStripItem subMenuItem in controllerToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems)
    {
        if (subMenuItem is ToolStripMenuItem)
        {
            subMenuItem.ImageIndex = 2;
            ToolStrip secondLevelParent = subMenuItem.GetCurrentParent();
            //secondLevelParent is of type ToolStripDropDownMenu
            //secondLevelParent.ImageList is null
        }
    }
}
```

In the example code above I try to add the image with index 2 to all submenu-items. This doesn't work! It might have to do with the fact that their parent is of type ToolStripDropDownMenu and its ImageList-property is null? The middle level item, *controllerToolStripMenuItem*, on the other hand shows the image correctly. Its parent is *menuStrip1* which has a valid refrence to my imagelist. How do I solve the problem with the submenu-items?

Comment: `controllerToolStripMenuItem` is direct child of the MenuStrip, so the ImageIndex could work on it. Setting the ImageIndex of sub-Items of `controllerToolStripMenuItem` won't do anything, since the parent doesn't have any ImageList attached. The `ImageIndex` property always gets the indexer from the `Owner`. Since you have a reference to the ImageList object, you can have `subMenuItem.Image = ImageList.Images[2];` -- BTW, do not post images of code. You're supposed to post your code as text, which is also much simpler that posting an image, since you can just copy/paste it here directly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and yes its definitely better to post code as text! I will do that next time :) I know that I can use the Image property instead, but my question is how to solve it with the ImageIndex property? If there is a way to propagate the ImageList down to the sub-items or make the submenu-items aware of the ImgeList in another way...

Comment: It's not *better* to post code as text, it's something you do out of respect for those who try to help you: images of code cannot be copied to test what your're  proposing in the OP and because it doesn't make sense to post as images something that is already text. -- As mentioned, the indexer that handles the ImageIndex property gets the index from the Item's `Owner`. A ToolStripMenuItem cannot have an ImagelIst attached: the child ToolStripMenuItem cannot get the Index from it. You have to build your own iterator that uses the original ImageList object and extends ToolStripItem.